# rails 3 where nested conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, where-clause

Ok so i have this

```
User.find(4).friends

 [#<Contact id: 67, type: nil, default_contact_group: false, primary_contact_id: nil, invitation_code: nil, flag_for_review: true, code_name: nil, reset_password_token: nil,  
.......
.......

User.find(4).friends.count
 => 5 

User.find(4).friends.map(&:type)
 => [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
```

as you can see all the type fields are nil but when i do this where clause i always return nothing

```
 User.find(4).friends.where("type != 'ContactGroup'")
 => [] 

 User.find(4).friends.where(["type != ?", "ContactGroup"])
 => []
```

what am i doing wrong and why is it not returning the records that this where clearly matches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the values of `type` column in your database are in fact `NULL`.

Then you now observe an interesting aspect of the `NULL` value. The result of a comparison of `NULL` with another value is neither `TRUE` nor `FALSE`, its `UNKNOWN`. Thus on your database a comparison of a value with `NULL` is never true, nor is the reverse ever true. That's why you don't see any results on your last query.

To mitigate this there is a special comparison operator: `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`. You can use it from rails like this:

```
User.find(4).friends.where(["type != ? or type IS NOT NULL", "ContactGroup"])
```

Answer (score 1):

`friends` is already an array, and will respond to [`.select`.](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-select)

```
User.find(4).friends.select {|f| f.type != 'ContactGroup'}

# Or .reject
User.find(4).friends.reject {|f| f.type == 'ContactGroup'}
```

Comment: And now imagine that the friends list is huge. You really don't want to filter that in Ruby when you can do it in the database...

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the column name `type` because of how Rails implements single table inheritance.  [This article explains in more detail](http://benv.ca/2007/1/16/legacy-rails-beware-of-type-columns/).

It's still applicable to Rails 3.  In the Rails 3 console, I get this error when trying to do the same kind of actions you are attempting.

> ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound: The single-table inheritance mechanism
>   failed to locate the subclass: 'test'. This error is raised because
>   the column 'type' is reserved for storing the class in case of
>   inheritance. Please rename this column if you didn't intend it to be
>   used for storing the inheritance class or overwrite
>   VideoFile.inheritance_column to use another column for that
>   information.